# Who do I bow down to the feet and who to the hand?

Tags: rituals, dharma

Every time I see a person from my Father's family, my parents ask me to bow down to their feet. However, when I see someone like my 'mama' (mother's brother) or an unrelated elder person I have to bow to their hand only. I don't understand why this is so. Why bow differently to certain people?

Comment: I have a question-What about the female relatives from ur mother's side?Do u not bow down to their feet?..after ur response i may be able to post an answer..

Comment: @Rickross Yes. Any one on my mothers side is to be bowed down to the hand and not the feet. Any one from my father's side however is to be bowed to the feet.

Comment: Sorry...i cud not gather sufficient materials for an answer..But here are few of my findings..1)Although one who initiates is called the Guru but "Guru" ,in general ,denotes many others like the parents,brothers,maternal uncles and in general elders.Of these the most venerable is of course the Guru(the teacher) then come the parents and then the rest..2)In Scriptures we have the concept that one shud not honor or prostrate before "inferior Gurus" when a "superior Guru" is present there.....

Comment: ....For eg where one's Guru is present the student shudn't prostrate before elder relatives..So,in order to justify ur family practice it is sufficient to show that a)Parents and relative from father's side have similar importance as "Gurus" but b)Parents are superior than the relatives from the mother's side as "Gurus"...But i was not able to prove that..I cudn't find anything yet in scriptures..

Comment: Interesting question; if also could describe in detail what bowing down to the feet is, and describe in detail what bowing down to the the hands is, could be helpful. Thank you :)